# Issue on Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am getting this error on browser console.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8069/api/login_prakriti_user' from origin 'http://localhost:8002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access baontrol check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My webpack file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
   entry: "./src/App.js",
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "bundle/js"),
      filename: "index_bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/",
   },
   devServer: {
     inline: true,
     port: 8002,
     historyApiFallback: true,
     disableHostCheck: true,
     proxy: { "/api": { target: "http://localhost:8069", changeOrigin: true } },
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
      {
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       loader: "babel-loader",
       query: {
       presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
      },
    },
    {
     test: /\.s?css$/,
     use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    },
    {
     test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
     loaders: ["url-loader"],
    },
   ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: "public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

This is my JS File with axios function:

```
path = /api/login_prakriti_user
return axios({
  method,
  url: "http://localhost:8069" + path,
   ...options
}).then((res) => {
if(res.data.success) {
  return res;
} else if(!res.data.tokenSuccess) {
  logout();
  toast.error(res.data.message);
} else {
  return;
}
}).catch((e) => {
  if (e.response && e.response.status === 401){
    toast.error(e.response.data.message);
  } else {
    return e
  }
})
}
```

I am calling this function in python file.

```
  @http.route('/api/login_prakriti_user', methods=['POST'], type='http', auth='public', website=True, csrf=False, cors="*")

  def user_login(self, **kwargs):
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to disable CORS on server side.

Comment: The proxy setting means that you need to use the same domain as the frontend, so `http://localhost:8002/api/login_prakriti_user` instead.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I cant call the same domain with port 8002 because the python API works on 8069. I am running python odoo server on 8069.

Comment: Yes, and you have a proxy set up that will redirect calls to localhost:8002/api to localhost:8069/api (`proxy: { "/api": { target: "http://localhost:8069", changeOrigin: true } }`). That's the whole purpose of the proxy.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I already applied this solution but forget to remove from JS function.
  Thanks for the help.
 Please do one favour , Please tick or upvote my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated JS file:

Pass only function name in url and pass proxy in webpack file.

```
 return axios({
    method,
    url: /api/login_prakriti_user,
     ...options
    }).then((res) => {
    if(res.data.success) {
      return res;
    } else if(!res.data.tokenSuccess) {
      logout();
      toast.error(res.data.message);
    } else {
       return;
   }
   }).catch((e) => {
     if (e.response && e.response.status === 401){
      toast.error(e.response.data.message);
     } else {
       return e
     }
   })
  }
```